# Accessing Maps from Google Apps script bound to form

Tags: google-apps-script, maps

I’m trying to access Maps from a script bound to a Google form. The problem i’m having is that when debugging the script, it accesses Maps so often that i’m Running into quota limits.  I have a Maps API key but do not have a client ID so can’t get Maps.setAuthenication(clientID,Key) to work. I’m doing this for a Scout Troop so don’t want to have to pay to access maps.

Can anyone help?

I was subsequently asked to post my code, and so here it is:

```
 function setLocation(){
     var whereString;
     var theDuration;
     var theDistance;
     var theRoute;
     var theDirections;
     var theTravelString; 

     // this Sets the Where: Tab on the form
     whereString = 'Where: ' + gLocation;
     theItemArray = gSignupForm.getItems();
     theItemArray[kWhereItem].setTitle(whereString);
     //this gets the directions to the location
     Maps.setAuthentication('','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'); 
     //Obviously Im'm not going to post the true key
     theDirections = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
         .setOrigin('7101 Shadeland Ave, Indianapolis, IN 46256')
         .setDestination(gLocation)
        .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
        .getDirections();
     theRoute = theDirections.routes[0];
     theDuration = theRoute.legs[0].duration.text;
     theDistance = theRoute.legs[0].distance.text;
     theTravelString = Utilities.formatString('Travel Considerations: The estimated travel distance is %u miles. ',theDistance);
     theTravelString += 'The estimated travel time is ' + theDuration;
     theItemArray[kTravelItem].setTitle(theTravelString);
}
```

Comment: Please share your code and explain what you are trying to achieve and what the expected outcome is. Also, please read 'How to ask' https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Consider using CacheService to avoid repeatedly re-querying the same information. I.e. once you generate the data from a given origin-destination pair, store that in cache for up to 6 hours. Then modify the given bits here to first check cache before querying Maps.

Comment: Per [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)), unless you have a Maps API for Business account you aren't going to be able to use `setAuthentication`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to limit the use of low-quota services is to avoid calling those services when the desired information has not changed.

For example, through the use of [`CacheService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/), you can dramatically reduce your calls to the Maps API, debugging session or not:

```
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
function setLocation() {
  // Try to find the route for this location if it's still available
  var storedRoute = cache.get(gLocation);
  if (!storedRoute) {
    // No route for this value of the key gLocation was found. Query as normal.
    ...
    theRoute = theDirections.route[0];
    // Cache this route for future uses, for the maximum of 6hr).
    cache.put(gLocation, JSON.stringify(theRoute), 21600);
  } else {
    // We have this exact stored route! Convert it from the stored string.
    theRoute = JSON.parse(storedRoute);
  }
  theDuration = ...
  ...
```

Your "gLocation" variable may be directly usable as a cache key. If not, you'll need to make it useable by encoding it. The max length key is 250 characters. This single-parameter caching assumes your directions all have a fixed endpoint, as shown in your example code. If both endpoints vary, you'll have to construct a cache key based on both values.

Related question: [Maps direction Quota limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418298/maps-direction-quota-limits)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will try that.