# Custom Sheets function to be used with ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-directions-api, google-sheets-custom-function

I am trying to use the following custom function `DrivingKms` with  `ARRAYFORMULA` so that it recursively calculates the distance down the specified columns.

How can I update it so that it works with `ARRAYFORMULA`?

```
function DrivingKms(origin, destination) {
  
  return DrivingMeters(origin, destination)/1000;
}

function DrivingMeters(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}
```

When I call the function in an `ARRAYFORMULA`, from all the way down, it only converts the first two location points (F2 and M2).

```
={"DrivingKms";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",drivingkms(F2:F, M2:M)))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use `DrivingKms` with `={"DrivingKms";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",drivingkms(F2:F, M2:M)))}`.

For this, I would like to propose the following modified scripts.

### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `DrivingMeters` is correct. But when `DrivingKms` is used with `={"DrivingKms";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",drivingkms(F2:F, M2:M)))}`, only the 1st element is used. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- When `drivingkms(F2:F, M2:M)` is used, `F2:F` and `M2:M` are the 2 dimensional array, respectively. In your case, it is required to considere this.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the result values are retrieved in the loop. Please modify `DrivingKms` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function DrivingKms(origin, destination) {
  return origin.map(([v], i) => [v && destination[i][0] ? DrivingMeters(v, destination[i][0]) / 1000 : ""]);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, from `recursively calculates the distance down the specified columns.`, the result values are retrieved in the recursive loop. For this, at first, `values` for using at `calc` is created. Please modify `DrivingKms` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function DrivingKms(origin, destination) {
  const calc = (values) => values.map ? values.map(calc) : DrivingMeters(...values.split(",")) / 1000;
  return calc(origin.map(([v], i) => [v, destination[i][0]].join(",")).filter(([a, b]) => a && b));
}
```

### Note:

- Please use above script with V8.

### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Yes, you have understood the issue correctly, although when I make both of your suggested changes I'm getting this result error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'legs' of undefined`

Comment: sorry, I was referencing the incorrect columns in my formula. Using both of you suggestions works! :) - a side question: do you know the daily quota limit set by Google to calculate distance?

Comment: @Roggie Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, this official document might be useful. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)) And, when you want to obtain the detail limitation, how about testing it in your environment? Because I have no information about the detail of current limitation. This is due to my poor experience. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Roggie Also, these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21418298 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/78222